# Has an IV even been performed or attempted in space?

Tags: astronauts, medical

As many of you likely know, IV's are an important part of modern medicine. As more and more people go into space for longer periods, I would imagine it may become necessary for an IV to be administered in space. It doesn't seem initially that this would face a lot of challenges to be performed in zero gravity from a mechanistic point of view since many IV's use a pump to control flow rate.

Is there any history of IV's either being administered or tested on a person or skin+vein stand-in? If not, is there a reason other than lack of interest?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first IV in space was performed on Space Shuttle Mission STS-55 in 1993.

> Harris, a medical doctor, set up first I.V. (intravenous) line in
>   space, injecting Schlegel with saline as part of study to replace body
>   fluids lost during adaptation to weightlessness. Other payload crew
>   members also participated.

[Source](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/shuttle/shuttlemissions/archives/sts-55.html)

Info on Bernard [Harris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernard_A._Harris_Jr.) and Hans [Schlegel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Schlegel).

There's a whole IV section in the [ISS Medical Checklist](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/163533main_ISS_Med_CL.pdf).